# Remove the theme info from main dashboard screen- not appearance

Tags: admin-menu

I've successfully used the code from the post:
Restrict ADMIN menu items based on username, replace username with an actual user's name.

The problem is the theme still shows on the main dashboard and by clicking on the theme name the admin is taken to the appearance menu which had been hidden by using the code.

Any thoughts how to get around this?

Here is the code from the post mentioned:

```
function remove_menus()
{
global $menu;
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if($current_user->user_login == 'clients-username')
{
    $restricted = array(__('Posts'),
                        __('Media'),
                        __('Links'),
                        __('Pages'),
                        __('Comments'),
                        __('Appearance'),
                        __('Plugins'),
                        __('Users'),
                        __('Tools'),
                        __('Settings')
    );
    end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu)){
        $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
    }// end while

}// end if
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this via javascript. The class of the theme informations is `versions` and the ID of this Meta Box is `dashboard_right_now`.

The follow screenshot demonstrate how I find this class and id via Crome Webinspector.

[image]

```
    add_action( 'admin_footer-index.php', 'fb_remove_comments_areas' );
    function () {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
                $( '#dashboard_right_now .versions' ).remove();
            });
            //]]>
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

For more hints to this topic see [this plugin](https://github.com/bueltge/Remove-Comments-Absolutely), that remove all comments functions and areas.

Also another hints. To remove menu or submenu items it is better, that you use the core functions `remove_menu_page()` and `remove_submenu_page()`. Also more information and examples in [this post](http://wpengineer.com/2233/remove-menu-item-in-wordpress-admin-panel/) or via search on WPSE. The last one is to use a plugin, there have options for this, like "[Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/)" for reduce the admin area for different roles, not user.

Comment: Welcome. Please set the check(arrow) to the answer, if the answer was your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below to remove the "Right Now" Widget.  Then there would be no way "Theme" to click on.

```
function custom_dashboard_widgets(){
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);        
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'custom_dashboard_widgets' );
```